# High value resistors go higher in value; high voltage resistors go higher in value

Tags: voltage, resistors, component-failure

During repairs of vintage hifi I occasionally observe two failure modes with resistors:

1. High-value resistors, say hundreds of K-ohms, go 30-100% higher in value.
2. Resistors connected to relatively high voltages go *much* higher in value, e.g. recently 47K became 1.9M, and I have seen 15K become 1.5G while definitely still conducting. In both cases there was about 300V at one end.

These are only two recent examples out of dozens or hundreds over ten or more years.

Vacuum tube anode load resistors are a familiar case of both. It is a commonplace among hifi restorers that you will have to replace the anode loads but usually not the cathode loads, and I don't remember ever having to replace a grid leak resistor, which are typically 330K-1M but have zero voltage across them statically.

The phenomenon happens even if the currents concerned are tiny or non-existent: for example, the 47k above was the anode load of a tube whose heater wasn't heating, so it wasn't conducting at all (in theory). Maybe *especially* in these cases.

I am wondering what the underlying failure mode is, and what high voltage has to do with it.

These are typically carbon composition or carbon film resistors, given the age of the equipment.

Comment: Go higher... in what regard? Are the resistors smoking (hot)?

Comment: @HarrySvensson Higher in value, as stated: 47K became 1.9M etc.

Comment: Okay, so in resistance. Cool.

Comment: Were the resistors exposed to a high temperature evironment?

Comment: @Dejvid_no1 Only what is normal inside a domestic vacuum-tube device.